# How to use NPM modules in plane javascript and html project?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, axios

I want to use axios in my simple project but it doesn't work but when I use CDN for axios it works..!!

**HERE'S THE MY CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script type="module" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
import {  axios } from ("axios");

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get("https://swquotes.herokuapp.com/random");
  console.log(data);
};
window.onload = getData();
```

I want to know ho can i use npm packages directly in my project without react

Comment: You can use CDN as you mentioned yourself!

Comment: @DamianBusz Can't i use direct npm packages in such kind of projects ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to node_modules then you can import it directly from the folder, even though thats dirty and is not recommended.

```
<script src="node_modules/<your_package>/dist/<entry_file>"></script>
```

Your problem is a little different, just to narrow it a little down - the browser doesnt understand your import statement as it has to be transpiled with webpack.

```
import {  axios } from ("axios");
```

So unless you import directly from CDN or use our dirty shown way of importing it - it wont and should not work